# Get parents text data using "this" jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, onclick, parent

I have the following HTML structure in my document HTML STRUCTURE

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to grab the `info__meta-dates` text so only the date using an `onClick` event in jQuery, this is the code that I have so far:

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
       
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .parent()
                .parent()
                .find(".info__meta--dates")
                .text()
         );
});
```

But I also get the `date` text that is within the nested span.

Comment: Hi did you tried below code ?

Comment: @Swati Hi, yes it works perfect! just added your solution as the one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `clone` that span tag and using `.remove()` remove `mdc-typography--caption` from the cloned element so that final result will be only the text which you needed

***Demo code*** :

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(e) {
  var texts = $(this).closest(".ev-info_meta").find(".info__meta--dates").clone(); //clone that span tag
  texts.find('span.mdc-typography--caption').remove(); //remove elemnt with class mdc-typography--caption
  console.log(texts.text().trim()); //show 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ev-info_meta">
  <span class="info__meta--dates"><span class="mdc-typography--caption">dates</span> fffff</span>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no direct element to get the date, you can try the above method explained by Swati and if you are not willing to remove the element from the DOM then try the string manipulation method.

The below method only works for this scenario.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
       
         let dateString =  $(this).parent()
                .parent()
                .parent()
                .find(".info__meta--dates")
                .text()
         );
       //removing the "date" string from the entire string
       let date = dateString.substring(4,dateString.length).trim();
       console.log(date);
});
```